# I get the error "Invalid item ID firebaseappcheckinterop-16.0.0-beta01" during build

Tags: c#, android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The question is as the title suggests.

The environment is Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio 2019 on Windows.

The error is not occurring in another project, and I think it's a bad NuGet included in the project...

The difference between a project that generates an error and one that does not is that you may or may not have updated the NuGet package when you started the project.

The NuGet packages included in the project that generate the error are as follows
-Xamarin.Firebase.Auth v121.0.1.1
-Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth v6.9.2
-Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging v4.7.1
-Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Storage v3.9.1
-Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging v122.0.0
-Xamarin.Firebase.Storage v120.0

The NuGet packages included in the project that do not generate errors are as follows
-FirebaseAdmin v2.1.0

I haven't tried most of the methods that seem to be effective, so perhaps any advice would be helpful.

I only tried the procedure to rebuild after deleting the bin and obj folders in all folders.

I'm sorry to bother you, but I'm looking forward to your answer and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is happening due to the Xamarin.Build.Download package doing some aggressive package id format checking. It doesn't like that `-beta01` postfix.

More details at the issue I opened on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/issues/1293

For an immediate solution, I suggest either:

- Downgrade to versions of Xamarin.Firebase.* that do not include preview packages as a transitive dependency
- Fork the XamarinComponents repo and remove or modify the id check (as detailed in the above linked github issue). Ideally this would be a band-aid fix until a newer version of Xamarin.Build.Download allows for this situation or newer a version of Xamarin.Firebase.Functions doesn't depend on a preview dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer. 
I thought the answers were at least much more useful than my survey. 
I think it will be very useful for those who want to use the new version of NuGet, so if you see this post in the future, please try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, an error that appeared when updating to [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/488) source, and tried to downgrade to test it.

Xamarin.Firebase.Storage v120.0.0 version to v119.2.2, the corresponding error no longer occurs.

That's all.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).